# Identity involving Möbius function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show $\mu(n)\mu(n+1)\mu(n+2)\mu(n+3) = 0 $ if $n$ is positive integer.

If $n$ is not square free, then the problem holds. If $n$ is square free, then should I consider the cases if $n$ is even and odd? any suggestion how to tackle this problem? thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with möbius inversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of $n$, $n+1$, $n+2$ and $n+3$ is divisible by $4$ and therefore not square-free.

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

We know, among $4$ consecutive integers, one is divisible by $4=2^2$